# Improve view performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, select, view

I need to improve my view performance, right now the SQL that makes the view is:

```
select tr.account_number , tr.actual_collection_trx_date ,s.customer_key
from   fct_collections_trx tr,
       stg_scd_customers_key s
where  tr.account_number = s.account_number
and    trunc(tr.actual_collection_trx_date) between s.start_date and s.end_date;
```

Table fct_collections_trx  has 170k+-(changes every day) records.

Table stg_scd_customers_key has 430mil records.

Table fct_collections_trx  have indexes as following:
  (SINGLE INDEX OF ALL OF THEM) (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACTUAL_COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_ACTION_CODE)(UNIQUE) and ENTRY_SCHEMA_DATE(NORMAL). DDL:

```
alter table stg_admin.FCT_COLLECTIONS_TRX
add primary key (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACTUAL_COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_ACTION_CODE)
  using index 
  tablespace STG_COLLECTION_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
   (
    initial 80K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

Table structure:

```
create table stg_admin.FCT_COLLECTIONS_TRX
(
  account_number              NUMBER(10) not null,
  sub_account_number          NUMBER(5) not null,
  actual_collection_trx_date  DATE not null,
  customer_key                NUMBER(10),
  sub_account_key             NUMBER(10),
  schema_key                  VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  collection_group_code       CHAR(3),
  collection_action_code      CHAR(3) not null,
  action_order                NUMBER,
  bucket                      NUMBER(5),
  collection_trx_date         DATE not null,
  days_into_cycle             NUMBER(5),
  logical_delete_date         DATE,
  balance                     NUMBER(10,2),
  abbrev                      CHAR(8),
  customer_status             CHAR(2),
  sub_account_status          CHAR(2),
  entry_schema_date           DATE,
  next_collection_action_code CHAR(3),
  next_collectin_trx_date     DATE,
  reject_key                  NUMBER(10) not null,
  dwh_update_date             DATE,
  delta_type                  VARCHAR2(1)
)
```

Table stg_scd_customers_key have indexes : (SINGLE INDEX OF ALL OF THEM)
(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, START_DATE, END_DATE). DDL :

```
create unique index stg_admin.STG_SCD_CUST_KEY_PKP on stg_admin.STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, START_DATE, END_DATE);
```

This table is also partitioned:

```
partition by range (END_DATE)
(
  partition SCD_CUSTOMERS_20081103 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2008-11-04 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace FCT_CUSTOMER_SERVICES_DATA
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    )
```

Table structure:

```
create table stg_admin.STG_SCD_CUSTOMERS_KEY
(
  customer_key   NUMBER(18) not null,
  account_number NUMBER(10) not null,
  start_date     DATE not null,
  end_date       DATE not null,
  curr_ind       NUMBER(1) not null
)
```

I Can't add filter on the big table(need all range of dates) and i can't use materialized view. This query runs for about 20-40 minutes, I have to make it faster..
I've already tried to drop the trunc, makes no different.

Any suggestions?

Explain plan:

[image: This is the explain plan for the query]

Comment: Probaby `trunc(tr.actual_collection_trx_date) between` is the weak point.

Comment: Already tried to remove it, doesn't seems to make a different @jarlh

Comment: How many rows are returned? To transfer lots of data may take some time...

Comment: Somewhere around 170k, depending on the smaller table size.. @jarlh

Comment: How is the partitioning defined? Maybe the DDL for both tables and their indexes would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write the query using explicit `join` syntax:

```
select tr.account_number , tr.actual_collection_trx_date ,s.customer_key
from fct_collections_trx tr join
     stg_scd_customers_key s
     on tr.account_number = s.account_number and
        trunc(tr.actual_collection_trx_date) between s.start_date and s.end_date;
```

You already have appropriate indexes for the customers table.  You can try an index on `fct_collections_trx(account_number,  trunc(actual_collection_trx_date), actual_collection_trx_date)`.  Oracle might find this useful for the `join`.

However, if you are looking for a single match, then I wonder if there is another approach that might work.  How does the performance of the following query work:

```
select tr.account_number , tr.actual_collection_trx_date,
       (select min(s.customer_key) keep (dense_rank first order by s.start_date desc)
        from stg_scd_customers_key s
        where tr.account_number = s.account_number and
              tr.actual_collection_trx_date >= s.start_date 
       ) as customer_key
from fct_collections_trx tr ;
```

This query is not exactly the same as the original query, because it is not doing any filtering -- and it is not checking the end date.  Sometimes, though, this phrasing can be more efficient.

Also, I think the `trunc()` is unnecessary in this case, so an index on `stg_scd_customers_key(account_number, start_date, customer_key)` is optimal.

The expression `min(x) keep (dense_rank first order by)` essentially does `first()` -- it gets the first element in a list.  Note that the `min()` isn't important; `max()` works just as well.  So, this expression is getting the first customer key that meets the conditions in the `where` clause.  I have observed that this function is quite fast in Oracle, and often faster than other methods.

Comment: Wow, took 10 seconds! Can you explain what does keep(dense_rank.... does? I'm not familiar with the function and i need to make sure it returns exactly the same as the original query @GordonLinoff

Comment: when i looked on the results of this query, I noticed that for each account number, no matter what is the date, the same key is returned.. Didn't look into it yet but i have a feeling its not right

Comment: @sagi . . . Oops, I left the `desc` out of the `order by`, so it was returning the first customer key rather than the last.  I don't think the change will affect performance.

Comment: Well, it works perfect, thanks a lot.. If you can i will appriciate a short explain about what that subselect does

Comment: @saig . . . I don't fully understand the reasoning.  It takes the minimum value of the first element in the list.  I think Oracle wanted a syntax that would be flexible, so you could do things like take the average of first three elements (although I've never used it for that purpose).

Answer (score 1):

If the start and end dates have no time elements (ie. they both default to midnight), then you could do:

```
select tr.account_number , tr.actual_collection_trx_date ,s.customer_key
from   fct_collections_trx tr,
       stg_scd_customers_key s
where  tr.account_number = s.account_number
and    tr.actual_collection_trx_date >= s.start_date
and    tr.actual_collection_trx_date < s.end_date + 1;
```

On top of that, you could add an index to each table, containing the following columns:

- for fct_collections_trx: (account_number, actual_collection_trx_date)
- for stg_scd_customers_key: (account_number, start_date, end_date, customer_key)

That way, the query should be able to use the indexes rather than having to go to the table as well.

Comment: The trunc doesn't matter, takes the same time without it.. and both of the tables have all the indexes you said besides Customer_key which I don't see how it can help the performance.. @boneist

Comment: Well, think about it. If the information isn't in the index, the query now has to go to the table. That's a two step process. If all the columns referenced in the query are in the indexes, then it's likely to be able to skip going to the table. What is the explain plan for this query? Please update your question to add that in.

Comment: When you say "both of the tables have all the indexes", what do you mean? Is there a single unique index on fct_collections_trx based on (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACTUAL_COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_TRX_DATE, COLLECTION_ACTION_CODE), or do you have an index per column?

Comment: Updated and added the explain plan. And its a single index, i can't alter the structure of this table since it is beeing used in a lot of other places(There is a reason why its built like this) @Boneist

Comment: You can't add additional indexes?

Comment: As requested by Alex, please can you update your question with the DDL for the tables as well as the indexes.

Comment: really? because I can't see the column definitions for either table.

Comment: Presumably you're testing the changes in a non-production environment; can you try adding the suggested indexes and see what impact that has on the query, please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  you an index based on the most selective field in your case

```
 START_DATE, END_DATE
```

try reverting the (or adding a proper)  index

```
 START_DATE, END_DATE, ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

in table `stg_scd_customers_key`

Comment: As i said in my post, the table already have those indexes.. @scaisEdge

Comment: I have see the index .. i suggest you to create and index in the order  i posted .. where the start_date and end_date became before  of the account_numebr ..in this way the index work much better.. and resolve the relation in minor time..